# How can we automate the testing for Google Analytics (Events, screen-views and their parameter) for android app

Tags: python, android, testing, automation

How can we automate the testing for Google Analytics (Events, screen-views and their parameter) for android app

On performing any action in android app such as tapping login button - GA event and screen-views are fired with many parameters. Manually testing all events and their parameters as per expected result is not feasible. What should be the best approach to automate this testing